# Debug Bluej for a Random Player

Tags: java, random, bluej

I'm trying to do a random method with BlueJ to play a random song of a playlist and then continue. My problem is that it just play one song and then stop. Here is my code. Hope someone can help me

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9493432

My error is that all songs start simultaneously.  Here is my code:

```
public void randomAllTracks(int index){ 
    if(indexValid(index)) { 
        for(Track track : tracks) { 
            player.startPlaying(track.getFilename()); 
            System.out.println("Now playing: " + track.getArtist() + " - " + track.getTitle()); 
            System.out.println(); 
            int randomTrack = (int)(Math.random() * tracks.size()); 
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: please post your code INLINE and describe your error.

Answer (score 0):

To get a random track that is always a valid index:

```
int randomTrack = (int)(Math.random() * tracks.size());
```

You can delete method randomTrack() because you don't need it.

You need some type of indication in class MusicPlayer to check whether the track is done.  Here, this is represented by trackFinished.  You can look at that variable as you play the song.

```
boolean trackFinished = true;

public void randomAllTracks(int index) { 
    while (true) {
        if (trackFinished) {
            playTrack((int)(Math.random() * tracks.size()));
            trackFinished = false;
        }
    }
}
```

MusicPlayer code:

```
public class MusicPlayer
{
    // The current player. It might be null.
    private AdvancedPlayer player;
    boolean finished = true;

    //some code

    public void startPlaying(final String filename)
    {
        try {
            setupPlayer(filename);
            Thread playerThread = new Thread() {
                public void run()
                {
                    try {
                        trackFinished = false;
                        player.play(5000);
                    }
                    catch(JavaLayerException e) {
                        reportProblem(filename);
                    }
                    finally {
                        killPlayer();
                        trackFinished = true;
                    }
                }
            };
            playerThread.start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            reportProblem(filename);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: all songs start simultaneously

Comment: then it stops again after the first song. It likes it can't work anymore. It stops the music but the machine continues working

Comment: trackFinished should be set to true when the song is finished, probably by some method in MusicPlayer.

Comment: I set the trackFinished in the method in MusicPlayer but nothing

Comment: you may want to post another question or edit to have MusicPlayer's code for checking if it's the end of the track.

Comment: Here is my entire code modifying with your code. 

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9494480

Comment: make trackFinished into an instance variable of MusicPlayer and create a getter method so randomAllTracks() can access it when it's checking.  When the track is finished, set the instance variable to true.  Your problem is with scoping of the boolean.

Comment: OMG I don't understand. Can you modify my code so I can understand better?

Comment: yeah the machine continues working but it stops the music after the first song

Comment: make sure trackFinished is true when the song stops and delete trackFinished's declaration in MusicOrganizer, instead call it player.trackFinished